# Is it safe to be showing my WAN and LAN IPs in my email headers?

Tags: network, email, ip

I don't know how to hide my LAN IP from my email recipients.
My LAN IP shows up next to my WAN IP in my outgoing email headers (sent to my other accounts and viewed by me). I have not seen emails sent to me showing other people's LAN IP in their headers that I can recognize. Some people have said they also see their LAN IP sent. Maybe a trait of Thunderbird client? It has no options to hide LAN IP. Thunderbird forum has no solutions. Any ideas?

Comment: If your LAN is, like most, NATtted onto an RFC1918 range then I'm not sure what security implications you are worrying about.  You can strip out headers in MTAs (like postfix) but I'm guessing you're using your ISPs service or gmail or something beyond your control ?

Answer (score 1):

Your local IP address is pretty much useless outside of your network. The only time you need to worry about if someone has your internal IP address is if they also have internal access to your network, either physically or via a Virtual Private Network (VPN). It's *very* hard to initiate a conversation with a device inside a network from outside the network, unless the network is willing to forward the connection (e.g. to a web server). The sole exception, of course, is if you use port forwarding or a demilitarized zone, in which case they don't need your local IP address anyways, since having the WAN IP is sufficient.

Also, you can read [bug 417942](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=417942) where this is discussed. Basically, Thunderbird is doing what *email* does: identify the path that the email took from start to finish, so it can be traced back/debugged/etc if necessary. It appears that Thunderbird only sends an IP address if there's no host name available, so if you were willing to set up a DNS server in your private network and assign your devices to host names, you could avoid having your internal IP address exposed.

The last comment basically sums up why this behavior is okay:

> ... Read RFC-2821:  "An Internet mail program MUST NOT
>   change a Received: line that was previously added to the message header.
>   SMTP servers MUST prepend Received lines to messages; they MUST NOT change
>   the order of existing lines or insert Received lines in any other location."
>
> It also specifies what goes into the Received: line.  Read section 4.4 of RFC-2821, and then tell me why we should violate this standard.
>
> ... The whole point of *precise* information identifying the host is so that the exact path taken by the message, and when, maybe clearly determined for tracing and diagnostic purposes.
>
> ... Thunderbird complies to the standard, and this is correct behavior.  I'm closing this bug.

In other words, any client that does not disclose either a host name or IP address is not in line with how the email protocol was designed to work.